# API response is not parsed by Axios after version update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I was using `axios` version `0.18.0`:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  responseType: 'json',
  baseURL: `api/v1/example`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
    Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
  },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  return response;
}, callback);

log: 
{
  "data": { foo: "bar" }, <---- this is typeof Array (JSON is parsed automatically)
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {},
  "config": {
  "transformRequest": {},
  ...and more
}
```

But after update to newest version, `1.6.2` and my app crashes because the JSON is not parsed properly anymore.

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  return response;
}, callback);

log: 
{
  "data": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}" <---- typeof string (JSON, its not parsed automatically)
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {},
  "config": {
  "transformRequest": {},
  ...and more
}
```

Why is my response is not parsed properly anymore? The response content type is:

`application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: perhaps AXIOS expects `application/json` as the `content-type` in the response - but that's OK, you can `JSON.parse` the `response.data` yourself since it's valid JSON - unlike [this poor soul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77637084/axios-returns-string-instead-of-object)

Comment: Does it work if you pass `responseType: "json"` to the instance's config?

Comment: Why are you setting a content-type header for all requests? Only requests with bodies require that header

Comment: @cbr I think your answer should be correct. Why did you delete it?

Comment: It was factually incorrect, I was reading the code for the default request transformer - not the response. I don't think axios looks at the content type of the response. The option transitional.forcedJSONParsing should default to true, so as long as responseType is not set, it should attempt to parse the data as JSON (see [source](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/b3be36585884ba1e237fdd0eacf55f678aefc396/lib/defaults/index.js#L102))

Comment: If that setting is not being applied by default, ensure you're importing `import axios from 'axios'`

Answer (score 1):

Axios should default to parsing the response as JSON, but your interceptor reveals that perhaps the defaults are not being applied in your axios instance. Make sure you're importing axios like `import axios from 'axios'` instead of e.g. `import { Axios } from 'axios'`.

If that doesn't work, you can explicitly tell Axios to treat the response as json with the `responseType` request config value:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  responseType: 'json',
  baseURL: `api/v1/example`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
    Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
  },
  responseType: 'json'
});
```

or with

```
axios.create({
  transitional: {
    forcedJSONParsing: true
  },
  // rest of config
})
```

It could also be that the JSON is malformed. Try setting `transitional.silentJSONParsing` to `false` in the config to find out (ensure responseType is set to "json" also)